# Flutter onTap get particular Image source from htmlWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have html coming from Json and saved it in the String and thereafter used `flutter_widget_from_html` dependency to view html as `webview`.

I want to get particular Image url onTap particular image in `htmlWidget`.
In android i have `onTouchListener` from where we can easily extract the image but I don't know how to do it in Flutter.

```
Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: HtmlWidget("<p><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-231636" src="http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/big13-48.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="800" srcset="http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/big13-48.jpg 600w, http://abc/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/big13-48-450x600.jpg 450w" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" /></p>", 
    webView: true,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Can you please add that html string here.

Comment: @AmitPrajapati i have edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using builderCallback. It provide you the functionality to customize the UI widgets while its rendering.

Follow this url.
https://github.com/daohoangson/flutter_widget_from_html/issues/50#issuecomment-500928520

Comment: It works.I don't know what is the best way to thank you.
I was stuck on this issue more than week. Thanks bhai

Comment: No problem buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  flutter_html: ^0.11.0
```

You will receive that image inside it.

```
 onImageTap: (src) {
   // Display the image in large form.
}
```

Reference link:

https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html

Comment: i have inline Css in html String but unfortunately ,this(flutter_html) dependency not worked with it. Thanks for help